# How to combine a literal string with regex?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I want to be able to search for a specific string then replace everything that follows it to a certain point.  Say for example I have this...
    `<sup id="cite_ref-19" class="reference">`
and this...
    `<sup id="cite_ref-22" class="reference">`
and I want all instances of `<sup>` tags removed, what would be the regex for this?  When I search Google, none of the sources include literal strings.  I plan on using the regex inside a `preg_replace`.  Much help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Question is not clear. Add input and desired output please.

Comment: Well.  Can't really try anything I don't know how to do and that Google doesn't have the answer as well.  `[A-Za-z0-9-_.+%]` is about as far as I have.  How do I add strings to that?  And I did explain the input and desired output.  If I have `<sup id="cite_ref-19" class="reference">` and `<sup id="cite_ref-22" class="reference">` how can I find all instances of the sup tag in order to replace them with nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the part of your question where you say 'I want all instances of `<sup>` tags removed' is your actual requirement (it is not easy to tell what you are asking for) then you just need to find all the `<sup>` tags and remove them. The following should find every `<sup>` tag and then you can replace them with `''` to remove them:

```
<sup .*?>
```

If this is not the question you are asking please attempt to clarify your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I had no idea it was so simple.  Thank You!